# Remove Headers of Jmeter output CSV file

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have changed the Jmeter property file as per my requirement.
Everything is working fine but I don't want to save labels(headers) to my csv file.

So how i can do this ?

Here is my jmeter.propertie file in which I have edited Result File Configuration part:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Results file configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This section helps determine how result data will be saved.
# The commented out values are the defaults.

# legitimate values: xml, csv, db. Only xml and csv are currently supported.
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv


# true when field should be saved; false otherwise

# assertion_results_failure_message only affects CSV output
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
#
# legitimate values: none, first, all
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=none
#
#jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
# response_data is not currently supported for CSV output
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
# Save ResponseData for failed samples
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=false

# Timestamp format - this only affects CSV output files
# legitimate values: none, ms, or a format suitable for SimpleDateFormat
#jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

# For use with Comma-separated value (CSV) files or other formats
# where the fields' values are separated by specified delimiters.
# Default:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=,
# For TAB, since JMeter 2.3 one can use:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=\t

# Only applies to CSV format files:
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=false

# Optional list of JMeter variable names whose values are to be saved in the result data         files.
# Use commas to separate the names. For example:
#sample_variables=SESSION_ID,REFERENCE
# N.B. The current implementation saves the values in XML as attributes,
# so the names must be valid XML names.
# Versions of JMeter after 2.3.2 send the variable to all servers
# to ensure that the correct data is available at the client.

# Optional xml processing instruction for line 2 of the file:
#jmeter.save.saveservice.xml_pi=<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"     href="../extras/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl"?>

# Prefix used to identify filenames that are relative to the current base
#jmeter.save.saveservice.base_prefix=~/
```

Answer (score 1):

This is controlled by:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=false
```

So your config seems fine.

Move it to user.properties to be sure it is not configured there with another value.